# Android TimePicker 12 hour format

Tags: android, timepicker

I have `TimePicker` in my Registration class to ask the user for their free time each day but it display the time in 24 hour format and I don't know how to view the time in a 12 hour format

I'm getting the value of `TimePicker` using

```
int hour = timepicker.getCurrentHour();
int min = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();

String time = hour + ":" + min;
```

and I also want to get the value of AM/PM

Comment: post more code, code for getCurrentHour() and getCurrentMunite() would be useful

Comment: sorry its `timepicker.getCurrentHour();` and `timepicker.getCurrentMinute();` updated my question

Answer (score 1):

```
int hour = timepicker.getCurrentHour(); 
int min = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();
String state = "am"; 
if(hour > 12){
    hour -=12;
    state = "pm";
}    
String time = hour + ":" + min + ":" + state;
```

PS: if you want the view itself show the time in *12-hours* format you can add `timepicker.setIs24HourView(false);`

Comment: what is the output of the string ?

Comment: only the time and min 16:8

Comment: how 16 stays without subtracting 12 , please check again, your value means hour was 28 before the if condition !

Comment: is this right `hour -=12;` in your code ? or it should be = -12;?

Comment: yea you can write also `hour = hour - 12;` , `=-12` will assign the hour as -12 , but we just want to subtract 12 from the current value

Comment: Why the output string doesn't has am beside it ?